# java 15 jar : comman not found oracle JDK

Tags: java, jar

hola un saludo debo crear unos jars `file.jar` usando `jar -cf` o `jar -cvf` por ejempo pero al correrlo me da el error

```sh
~$ jar -cf package.jar packageExample/
zsh: command not found: jar
```

instale java 15 de oracle usando `dpkg -i jdk-15_linux-x64_bin.deb`

ruta : `cd /usr/lib/jvm`

```sh
jvm tree -L 1 .
.
├── default-java -> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
├── java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-11-openjdk-amd64
├── java-11-openjdk-amd64
└── jdk-15
```

tengo las siguientes configuraciones:

```sh
~ cat /etc/environment      
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15"
```

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15/bin/java" 0
```

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15/bin/javac" 0
```

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15/bin/java
```

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.2/bin/javac
```

```sh
update-alternatives --list java
```

```sh
update-alternatives --list javac
```

luego cierro sesion yal correr `java -version` y `javac -version`

```sh
➜  ~ java -version
java version "15" 2020-09-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)
➜  ~ javac -version
javac 15
```

estoy usando  Ubuntu 20.04 y zsh ohmyzsh

gracias de antemano

Comment: **correccion:**  en el comando `sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.2/bin/javac`  la parte de _**/jdk-15.0.2/**_  use _**/jdk-15**_ tal que asi :
`sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15/bin/javac`, person por eso

Comment: contenido de los archvios `~/.zshrc` y `~/.bashrc`;
`export PATH="$PATH:/user/lib/jvm/java-15/bin"`